# Second and second final values mixing up in two dimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, database, multidimensional-array, codeblocks

I am trying to learn code on Codeblocks, and I'm doing a code in which I input people's entry and exit times at a place, which are then stored in an array `time[entry/exit][personnumber]` through this code:

```
int peo;
cout << "How many entries were registered?" << endl;
cin >> peo;
int k = peo-1;
int time[1][k]; //array people x entry time (at time[0][x]) and exit time (at [1][x])
cout << "Please insert the entry and exit times, without ':' in order" << endl;
for (int i=0; i<=k; i++) { //Assigning values of entry and exit in order for each person
    for (int j=0; j<=1; j++) {
        cin >> time[j][i];
    }
```

Though, when checking the values `time[1][0]` (second value), and `time[0][k]` (second last value), they are the same. Somehow the code is mixing those up. I tried creating a temporary integer assigning `time[1][0]`'s value and then reassigning it later, but it messed my code even further. I used this code to check the values

```
for (int i=0; i<=k; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<=1; j++) {
        cout << time[j][i] << " [" << j << "]" << "[" << i << "]"  << endl;
    }
}
```

What is happening?

Comment: The for loops should use `<` instead of `<=`. Otherwise you get out-of-bounds access for the arrays.

Comment: `int array[1]` how many fields will such array have?

Comment: And you defined only one array entry: `int time[1][k];` Does not matter how many dimensions you have, for each of them applies: `X x[n];` gives you an array with `n` entries, accessible via indices `[0; n-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array really only has one "row" in the first dimension, and due to some really funky syntax and C++ architecture revolving around pointers time[0][k] and time [1][0] are actually looking at the same spot. Explanation to follow, but to fix your problem intstead of `int time[1][k];` you should declare `int time[2][k];` to get your two first dimension "rows". To access element j in the first row, since C++ indexes from 0, use `time[0][j]`. For element j in the second row, use `time[1][j]`.

Additionally, C++'s indexing-from-zero property causes time[0][k] to be undefined, since the second dimension's indicies go from 0 to k-1.

`int time[2][k];` will initialize the following array:

Index: 0 ..1 .. 2  .......  k-2  k-1

0 ----    [ _ ][ _ ][ _ ] ...  [ _ ] [ _ ]

1 ----    [ _ ][ _ ][ _ ] ...  [ _ ] [ _ ]

Comment: Actually, both of `[0][k]` and `[1][0]` are undefined behaviour, as both access the array out of bounds! The former, according to the standard, even is UB if array was defined as `[2][k]`(!), whereas the latter would not...